# Использование Scanner вместо BufferedReader

Tags: java

Как этот же код реализовать с использованием `Scanner`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //напишите тут ваш код
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //Попытка правильного кода
    String a = "";
    boolean b = true;
    int iN = 0;
    while (b) {
        System.out.println("Введите номер дня недели: \t");
        a = reader.readLine();
        if (a.matches("\\d+")) {
            iN = Integer.parseInt(a);
            b = false;
            switch (iN) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("понедельник");
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("вторник");
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("среда");
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    System.out.println("четверг");
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    System.out.println("пятница");
                    break;
                }
                case 6: {
                    System.out.println("суббота");
                    break;
                }
                case 7: {
                    System.out.println("воскресенье");
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    System.out.println("такого дня недели не существует. Введите правильный номер дня");
                    b = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вместо а = reader....... Пиши а = new Scanner(java.lang.System.in).nextInt();

Comment: В вопросе не содержится описания проблемы. С переписыванием какой именно части возникли сложности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вместо

   ```
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   ```

   пишем

   ```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   ```
2. Вместо

   ```
   a = reader.readLine();
   ```

   пишем

   ```
   a = scanner.nextLine();
   ```

---

Весь код можно укоротить так:

```
private static final String[] daysNames = { "понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота", "воскресенье" };

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isReading = true;
    while (isReading)
    {
        System.out.println("Введите номер дня недели: \t");
        try
        {
            int number = scanner.nextInt();
            if (number > 0 && number <= daysNames.length)
            {
                isReading = false;
                System.out.println(daysNames[number - 1]);
            }
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            scanner.next();
        }
        if (isReading)
        {
            System.out.println("такого дня недели не существует. Введите правильный номер дня");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: За упрощенный код отдельное спасибо.... вникаю)

Comment: @Malus на здоровье. Прежде чем писать `switch-case` или цепочку из `if-else if`, нужно всегда прикидывать: а не получится ли сделать то же самое с помощью массива, списка или `Map`, укоротив тем самым код и избавившись от дублирования кода.